# Is there anything special I have to do for a skinny pig?

Tags: guinea-pigs, skinny-pigs

As a kid, I had many many guinea pigs. I loved them, they were cute, and fun, and relatively easy for me to take care of. I was considering getting another one now that I am an adult, and then I saw skinny pigs. From what I can tell, they are a lot like guinea pigs, but hairless.

[image]

Keeping that in mind - if I decide that this is the pet I want, is their care the same as the average guinea pig? The person at the pet shop said that it was, but I know sometimes that people at pet stores don't know everything about every animal, so I wanted to make sure I was best prepared before I took on a new pet.

Do I have to do anything differently with a skinny pig than I would with a normal guinea pig?

Answer (score 4):

One thing I know is that their skin is delicate, so normal sawdust or straw can hurt them (scratches and stitches). For my bald rats, I used toilet paper, fleece blankets and towels instead. You also need to find a way to present them with lots of hay like 'normal' guinea pigs but in a way that they can't scratch themselves.

If the skin is dirty and the skinny pig fails to clean itself, you can take a wet and warm q-tip to clean it.